# Design Patterns - Database Columns Dependent on API Keys

Tags: design-patterns, database-design

I'm working on an iPhone app and am currently building out the Web API in PHP.  For this application, I'll be importing data from a 3rd party API to store in my server-side database periodically.

My Question: It would be easiest if each of my Database columns were named the same as the corresponding API key from which I'm pulling.  This way, imports are very easy.  However, my database will then be highly coupled to this 3rd party API, and if they decide to change their API keys one day, I'll have to change my database columns.

Whats the best way to handle this sort of situation?  Do I make some sort of key mapper?  Also, as I'm solving this issue, does this fall under a certain Design Pattern?  If so, I'd love to do more research into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing.  I decided to 'convert' the API keys on import form the API nomenclature, to my own.  This way, any changes to the 3rd party API only effect my Importing classes, not my Models.

I have a `Parser` class:

```
abstract class Parser {

    public function parse()
    {   
        $this->mapApiKeysToColumns();
    }

    protected function apiKeys()
    {
         // Gets First rows of CSV (columns)
         return $this->reader->fetchOne(0);
    }

    protected function mapApiKeysToColumns()
    {
        foreach($this->apiKeys() as $api_key) {
            array_push($this->keys, $this->key_mappings[$api_key]);
        }
    }

    protected function createArrayFromData()
    {
        // Gets first chunk of data from csv
        $this->reader->setOffset($this->offset)->setLimit($this->parse_chunk)->fetchAll(function($row, $offset) {
            // takes the Keys and combines them with the data
            array_push($this->data, array_combine($this->keys, $row));
        });
    }
}
```

And then each `Parser` implementation extends the base `Parser` class and provides the mappings

```
class AgencyParser extends Parser {

    protected $key_mappings = [
        'agency_id' => 'agency_id',
        'agency_name' => 'name',
        'agency_url' => 'url',
        'agency_timezone' => 'timezone',
        'agency_lang' => 'language',
        'agency_phone' => 'phone'
    ];
}
```

And then in my client code, i call `$parser->parse();`  The keys are then pulled from the API and cross-referenced against a Mapping Array.  This creates an array of the Keys that I use, and is merged with the data that I'm importing from the API.  Effectively, I'm doing a `grep` for the known API keys and replace them with my own key names.

So now, my data isn't completely dependent on the API keys.  If one or more of the API keys happen to change, I can simply update those keys in the `$key_mappings` and my application will still function as normal, without having to changes any of my database columns or any of my Model code.